Not able to use iCloud mail or create @icloud.com
I created an Apple account for a family member using phone number about a month ago. After the whole setup and software updates (now running on iOS 18.1.1), I opened iCloud mail to create an @icloud.com email. It showed iCloud mail is not available for your account. I then opened the browser and signed in to iCloud.com mail, and there also the same error was shown.
I then watched some tutorials on Youtube, and went to settings and clicked on the name, went to iCloud to toggle on 'Use iCloud mail on this device', but there was no button like that. Also in list of apps using iCloud there was no Mail app.
I have restarted the iPhone and reinstalled the Mail app but nothing helped. In the sign-in and security page there is also no option to create a new email - it only gives an option to add an existing email address.
I'm now using a Gmail account as primary mail temporarily but I want to create an @icloud.com email address.
Device - iPhone 15

Why wouldn’t you contact Apple Support online for questions relating to your Apple Account and iCloud features?

Did you provide an email address when you set up the account? Do any iCloud services work, such as Photos? Did you enable two-factor authentication?

@LincDavis When creating apple account there were two options 1) by using email 2) by using phone number, i first tried with using email but the page was stuck at loading page, then i tried again faced same issue then created apple account using phone number. No email address was asked. iCloud services work fine but the Mail app is not working and there is no option of Mail app under iCloud category. Two factor is also enabled.

@bmike After 30minutes of call support, they just told to create a new apple account. Like damn its something a normal people would think, then why are you sitting there as technical assistant

What is preventing you from doing what they advised?

@LincDavis I am logged into apple music,tv,arcade etc with the existing apple id. Although no purchase has been made, some icloud backups of about 20GBs, facetime, esim etc etc. If i create a new apple id i would face data transfer problem, in case of esim deletion it would be a problem, how do i transfer whatsapp backup of around 10gbs.. Other contacts calling me on facetime would be a problem

You can associate your phone number with a new account, after creating it with an email address. That should take care of the FaceTime issue. I'm not sure what you mean about "eSIM deletion." I don't know of any reason why your eSIM would be affected. The Apple ID/Account is only used to transfer an eSIM between devices. As for your backups, I don't know of anything you can do about that, unless Apple is willing to help you out, which I doubt they would be.

@LincDavis By esim deletion I mean that, is there any chances that esim will not work by changing apple id ?. I have backups of few files, which i can download on iphone storage. What about whatsapp backup ?. Some apps are also linked to apple id, will it work ?. Apple customer support created a ticket and told me to guide me on creation of new apple id and setup. But i am worried about my data. This is a headache, why cant i create icloud.com mail directly

Please follow the instructions under the heading "Change your Apple Account primary phone number to an email address" here:
Create and manage an Apple Account using a phone number instead of an email address (support.apple.com)

Thanks for this, i already have read this article earlier but there is no option to choose new icloud email address. Check out this image https://ibb.co/GJdqWSX

Use any working email address. You should be able to create an iCloud address afterwards.
